# Function is not returning await value

Tags: node.js, async-await

Here is my code.

```
let getMessage= await super.getResources(ctx, Flash, {where: {created_by: ctx.meta.userId}});
if(getMessage) {
    getMessage.forEach(employee);
    async function employee(item:any){
        console.log('Inside 1');
        if(item.effective_employees.length){
            console.log('Inside 2');
            for(let i=0;i<=(item.effective_employees.length -1);i++){
                let sql:string=`sqlQuery`;
                let data:any = await UserRepository.execQuery(ctx,Flash,sql);
                //let data = 1;
                console.log('Inside 3');
                if(data){
                    console.log('Inside 4');
                    item.effective_employees[i] = 'Data here from a function';
                    console.log(item.effective_employees);
                }
            }
            //return item;
        }
    }
    console.log('Inside 5');
    return Promise.resolve(getMessage);
```

If i am not using these lines or commenting out thease the return has `Data here from a function` in it.

```
            //let sql:string=`sqlQuery`;
            //let data:any = await UserRepository.execQuery(ctx,Flash,sql);
```

But if i use this without commenting the return type does not have `Data here from a function` In it.

I think my function is not waiting for the await and just passing the value which is there. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript async await doesn't work inside forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914162/javascript-async-await-doesnt-work-inside-foreach-loop)

Comment: If there is an await inside forEach it will work asynchronously so remove forEach with for loop

Comment: can some one give me an example here replacing for each?